# Same name for pakage and node

Tags: ros, rosnode, ros-kinetic, rospackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will it be a problem if the name of a ros package and a ros node within that package is same?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300077/same-name-for-pakage-and-node/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. The `amcl` package has a [node](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Nodes) called `amcl` and it works perfectly fine.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1